Linking data of duplicate objects with applied transformations
I have a 3d model that has many separate meshes in it. Many of those parts are identical objects, rotated on different axes. I ultimately want to link their mesh data, however since their rotation transformation is applied, I have to duplicate and rotate them manually. I am looking for a script that would go through selected objects (that I am sure they are duplicates), somehow find rotation value for each (maybe relative to the active object?), link their mesh data, then finally rotate them back to their original positions so that in the end we will have linked duplicates with different rotation values.
Just to illustrate the task, here are 4 identical objects with applied transformation. I want to have 4 linked objects that are rotated:


All the origins seem to be in the same local place, so if you select the same vertex in each object, you could have a script run through the objects and use trigonometry between the origin and the vertex's position to calculate the rotation of the first object, and the rotated objects, and use their difference to rotate it back
